# How to close this pop up in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

recently I updated my IntelliJ IDEA application and now every time I use parentheses a window pops out as shown in screenshot. Its very annoying as it occurs frequently.

screenshot

[image: 1]

the code
[image: 2]

Should I downgrade IntelliJ ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're having the same issue as [this Intellij user](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000037590-Disable-pop-up-that-prevents-typing-).

The response to fix it is:

`Disable the Show Parameter info option in Editor > General > Code Completion`
by [Awalvie](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/profiles/360145857324-Awalvie)

Looking at Android Studio for a similar state I believe it might be named `Show parameter name hints` now instead. There are a few options for this.

Comment: I tried to hide parameter but but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you uncheck "Show the parameter info popup in [1000] ms"? @utkarshx27

Comment: Just as the @Cayce K mentioned here, try to disable the `File | Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion | Show the parameter info popup in 1000 ms` option there to see if it helps.